# SfCalendar widget not updating when a new item is added

Tags: flutter

I am trying to update/refresh the [`SfCalendar`](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) widget whenever a new booking is added. I tried using `setState()`, but still it does not work. The newly added booking only appears when I switch to another Fragment (`AboutFragment`) and back (`CalendarFragment`).

Which part did I do wrong?

Here is the code:

`home.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

import '../booking.dart';
import '../pages/login.dart';

List<Booking> bookingList = <Booking>[];

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedFragment = 0;
  BookingDataSource _bookingDataSource = BookingDataSource(bookingList);

  void addNewBooking() {
    setState(() {
      Future<DateTime?> bookingDateTime = showBookingPicker(context: context);
      bookingDateTime.then((DateTime? value) {
        if (value != null) {
          bookingList.add(Booking('Reservation', value, value.add(const Duration(minutes: 30)), 'M'));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Booking Added'))
          );
          _bookingDataSource = BookingDataSource(bookingList);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('STS'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          MenuAnchor(
            builder: (BuildContext context, MenuController menuController, Widget? child) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (menuController.isOpen) {
                    menuController.close();
                  } else {
                    menuController.open();
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              );
            },
            menuChildren: [
              MenuItemButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const LoginPage(title: 'Log In'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.logout),
                      SizedBox(width: 4.0),
                      Text('Log Out'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _selectedFragment == 0 ? CalendarFragment(bookingDataSource: _bookingDataSource) : const AboutFragment(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0.0,
        tooltip: 'Add booking',
        onPressed: () {
          addNewBooking();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedFragment,
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedFragment = index;
          });
        },
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            label: 'My Booking',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            label: 'About Us',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CalendarFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  final BookingDataSource bookingDataSource;

  const CalendarFragment({Key? key, required this.bookingDataSource}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CalendarFragmentState();
}

class _CalendarFragmentState extends State<CalendarFragment>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.month,
      headerStyle: CalendarHeaderStyle(
        textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
      ),
      dataSource: widget.bookingDataSource,
      initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
      monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(showAgenda: true),
    );
  }
}

class AboutFragment extends StatelessWidget { ... }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for clarifying. Hopefully, this project is not a real project, it is for my portfolio only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the wrong usage of `setState` in the `addNewBooking` method. You're calling `setState` when showing the picker, but not when the value assignment to `_bookingDataSource` happens that is after the picker returning a value.

Do this instead:

```dart
void addNewBooking() {
  Future<DateTime?> bookingDateTime = showBookingPicker(context: context);
  bookingDateTime.then((DateTime? value) {
    if (value != null) {
      bookingList.add(Booking('Reservation', value, value.add(const Duration(minutes: 30)), 'M'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Booking Added'))
      );
      setState(() {
       _bookingDataSource = BookingDataSource(bookingList);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Or you can write it better with async function:

```dart
Future<void> addNewBooking() async {
  final value = await showBookingPicker(context: context);
  if (value != null) {
    bookingList.add(Booking(
        'Reservation', value, value.add(const Duration(minutes: 30)), 'M'));
    if (!mounted) return;
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Booking Added')));
    setState(() {
      _bookingDataSource = BookingDataSource(bookingList);
    });
  });
}
```